# Dynamics CRM Version 1710 (9.1.0.288) online Business Process Flow, ProcessId and StagedId are empty

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Customer upgraded from 8.2 online to Version 1710 (9.1.0.288) online
We have a BPF on Entity. BPF ProcessId and StageId of BPF are empty. We did advanced find to see and they show as empty.

We checked with another Organization and BPF on Opportunity Entity same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From v9.0 it is possible to have more than one active BPF per entity. 
To retrieve information about active BPF's, you should now use `RetrieveProcessInstancesRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

from version 9.0 and forward Business process flows are represented as they were entities, these to allow multiples processes for the same entity ([Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/business-process-flows-overview#business-process-flow-entity-customization-support))

Hope it helps